# Having trouble loading "neighbours" of a specific tile into a List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

this is my first time asking questions here, i'm actually having a problem in my script:
I'm trying to add the neighbors of a tile into a list, but i keep getting the NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to print what's inside the list.

To note that the first "list.Add" is actually working, the others aren't.
To test it i'm always trying to find something that exists, all Tile_(x)_(y) exists.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TileStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public List<GameObject> neighbours;

    public List<GameObject> populateNeighbours ()
    {
        List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
        //If we're at x, y.
        //Left one is at x-1,y
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x-1) + "_" + y));

        //Right one is at x+1,y
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x+1) + "_" + y));


        //Bottom ones are at x,y-1 and x+1,y-1
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y-1)));
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x+1) + "_" + (y-1)));

        //Top ones are at x,y+1 and x+1,y+1
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y+1)));
        list.Add(GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x+1) + "_" + (y+1)));
        return list;

    }
}


...
Tile_GO.GetComponent<TileStats>().x = x;
Tile_GO.GetComponent<TileStats>().y = y;
Tile_GO.GetComponent<TileStats>().neighbours=Tile_GO.GetComponent<TileStats>().populateNeighbours();
...
```

The error is thrown when i try to print the input:
    foreach (GameObject obj in ourHitObject.GetComponent().neighbours) {
                    print("Name: " + obj.name + "Atual: " + i++);
                }

SOLVED

> @AnthonyLeal I looked at the code and that is the problem. You are searching for GameObject while do they don't exist. Just think about it like this: Your generated a gameObject in your for loop then called the populateNeighbours() function in that for loop. That populateNeighbours() function does not operate on the generated GameObject in that loop. It looks for other GameObjects that are not yet generated. You did this many many times leading to over 500 errors. – Programmer

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Object reference not set" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487637/object-reference-not-set-error)

Comment: you're not showing all of your code, so nobody can help you.  note that quite simply YOU DO NOT SET "neighbors" anywhere.  Did you mean to set it in "populateNeighbours" ?

Comment: note that populateNeighbours **MUST** be called PopulateNeighbours, not populateNeighbours.  You need to change this and edit the code here to reflect it also.

Comment: on what line is NullReference being thrown ? Possibly its not finding one of the GameObject and that means the object does not exist.

Comment: I've just edited the post to clarify some things and sort of answer your questions

Comment: so we finally know which method actually trows an exception, now can you please explain what does the code you provide us in the beginning with has to do wiith that foreach?

Comment: The problem is probably in the code itself, when i try to add the object to the list, reading it should be fine, for example If i add to the list 6x"Left ones", ( x-1) ( y), it will run correctly. If i try to add any other ( right, top, bottom ) the error is thrown when printing.

Comment: @Joe Blow  He can call his code whatever he wants. It just wouldn't fly if he were to put it in front of an employer. But you can't dictate someone's coding style because you don't like it.

Comment: @AnthonyLeal  Are you using `GetComponent<TileStats>()`?

Comment: Yes i am, i'ts in the bottom of the code of what i sent. But in an other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is probably in the code itself, when i try to add the
>   object to the list, reading it should be fine, for example If i add to
>   the list 6x"Left ones", ( x-1) ( y), it will run correctly. If i try
>   to add any other ( right, top, bottom ) the error is thrown when
>   printing.

This is happening because the first `GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x-1) + "_" + y)` found the GameObject in the scene. The rest of the `GameObject.Find` method failed. When it fails, it returns `null`. That `null` is added to the `List` even though there is nothing there.

This is something no one can fix for you because we can't see the name of `GameObjects` in your scene. You have to fix it yourself by checking if the `GameObject.Find` returns `null` before adding it to the `List`. Replace your `populateNeighbours()` function with the function below to easily debug your code. It won't add the `GaeObject` if it is `null` and it will print the name of `GameObject` it couldn't find. You can then use it to check if that `GameObject` actually exist in the scene.

Also, **Don't** use `foreach`  to loop over List in Unity. Use `for` loop instead.

```
public List<GameObject> populateNeighbours()
{
    List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
    //If we're at x, y.
    //Left one is at x-1,y
    GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x - 1) + "_" + y);
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + (x - 1) + "_" + y + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    //Right one is at x+1,y
    tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + y);
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + y + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    //Bottom ones are at x,y-1 and x+1,y-1
    tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y - 1));
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y - 1) + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + (y - 1));
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + (y - 1) + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    //Top ones are at x,y+1 and x+1,y+1
    tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y + 1));
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + x + "_" + (y + 1) + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    tempObj = GameObject.Find("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + (y + 1));
    if (tempObj == null)
        Debug.Log("Tile_" + (x + 1) + "_" + (y + 1) + " Does NOT exist");
    else
        list.Add(tempObj);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm not getting the error anymore. Still, it's not working correctly. I'm not getting my neighbours:I will try to explain - I'm 'printing' the neighbours on a mouse event ( only to test if its working before I do something else with em ). In the logs, with your code it says that Tile_2_1 don't exist. BUT if i click on the tile 3_1, it will 'print' the Tile_2_1 as a neighbour, so it exists. Only the left one is printing. 
I'm calling the function whenever a tile is created, it's spamming Tile_x_y don't exist for nearly every tile.

Comment: @AnthonyLeal Of-course, the error should be gone because it is no longer adding null objects to the list. The next part is for you to check and make sure that the names match what you are printing.  "**BUT if i click on the tile 3_1, it will 'print' the Tile_2_1, so it exists.**" Don't click on anything. Look in the Scene Hierarchy to see if it exists. Also, are you generating the tiles on run-time or are the tiles there already before clicking play?

Comment: Yes, the tiles are there, in the Scene i have 11x11 tiles named. They are there in the hierarchy. It goes from Tile_0_0 to Tile_10_10. The name is correct, it's probably something dumb but i can't find the solution.

Comment: @AnthonyLeal Make sure there is no space in the beginning or the end of the GameObject name? This is hard to notice. Just Click on one of the Objects that it were not able to find and make sure there is no space in it. If that's not the problem then upload the program and send link here. I will take a look at it. You can remove important graphic files if you want. This is the only way I can help.

Comment: I'm just starting so it's pretty simple and should be easy to look at, the link is here. Thank you! https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_VQ3JxLXD5CMmltaEpqbDAzbGc

Comment: @AnthonyLeal I looked at the code and that is the problem. You are searching for `GameObject` while do they don't exist. Just think about it like this: Your generated a `gameObject` in your for loop then called the `populateNeighbours()` function in that for loop. That `populateNeighbours()` function does not operate on the generated `GameObject` in that loop. It looks for other `GameObjects` that are not yet generated. You did this many many times leading to over 500 errors.

Comment: @AnthonyLeal I fixed that part of problem by generating the `GameObjects` first in the for loop, then performing the other operation in another different for loop. The error is down from 506 to 86. Your new  `Map` script http://pastebin.com/vQDApx0i The remaining problem is from the `populateNeighbours()` function and I can't fix that because I don't know how that function work. The problem with that function is that it is searching for `GameObject` that is not even in the scene. The new error I think you can fix.

Comment: Just look at the new error and what Objects are created in the scene.  You may be able to adjust the x and y values from the` populateNeighbours()` function so that the object it is looking for is valid. No printed GameObject actually exist now. Use the the Map Script above.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't noticed that! If i may ask, where did you found those 86 errors, or even the 506 before you fixed this? I am not having any information of those. Well, it's solved, i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @AnthonyLeal Those are fake errors  I created with `Debug.Log`. I consider them as errors because `GameObject.Find` failed.  I was able to remove the 50 errors by removing x+1 and y+1 or -1 or anything that adds or removes one in your `populateNeighbours()` function. Just like I said, I don't know how your `populateNeighbours()`  works, and don't know if removing those will be good for the game your are making. Here is the new function http://pastebin.com/sqa1nAq9 . Your layout is bad and you need to reset it by following steps here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37289594/3785314.

Comment: As for how to find how many `Debug.Log` or error, look at the image here http://imgur.com/QVy13PZ I didn't want the Unity error to trigger so I used `if... == null` to check if which `GameObject` is `null` then used `Debug.Log` to display custom error message. This will tell me more information about the error than letting Unity throw and exception with the C# general null error message and abort or pause the game.

Comment: I could easily fix those errors by verifying if x or y is in the range of 0:10 since it will never exist a Tile_-1_11 for example. This should get rid of any problem with that code! You really helped!

Comment: @AnthonyLeal That's right. Since you have array with 11 objects, it starts from 0 to 10 not 1 to 11. The remaining error is accessing 11 and sometimes -1 which is messed up. You are welcome and happy coding!